# fill nodes/rows in tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, fill

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
        },
rows /. style={nodes={fill=gray!10, text=black}}
    }
}


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \\
B1 \& B2 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}



\end{document}
```

I tried this: `rows /. style={nodes={fill=gray!10, text=black}}`
in `tikzset` but it doesn't work.
Also I tried in nodes `fill=gray!10` but this also doesn't work?

I cannot believe that there is not something as simple as

```
row 1 /. style={nodes={fill=gray!10, text=black}}
```

but for all rows or equivalently all nodes?!?!

Comment: You can mark inline code with a leading and trailing `\`` (as Kurt did in his edit)

Comment: ? How is what you want different than simply putting these options in the `nodes={rectangle, ...}` above ?? Maybe you tried and simply did not notice it had worked due to extreme lightness of the `fill=gray!10` ...?

Comment: ok I'm sorry... you are actually right -.- I did not notice...

Comment: Oh well... I guess we learned a valuable lesson in debugging, then ! `;)` (to test with actually change-inducing settings, or something like that)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based off an erroneous assumption, and misleading as such, solved in the comments, and unlikely to be useful to anybody else.